# can you create a 3D component using JOGL?

Tags: java, user-interface, opengl, components, jogl

(system flagged this is being subjective but i don't see how, anyone explain ?)

Anyway, as my title asks,can you create a 3D component using JOGL?
What I'm trying to do is, imagine an empty cylinder. You cut the cylinder in two halves and you're looking into one half.
On the inside I want to stick images...not entirely sure to what purpose this will serve yet but i'm playing around with JOGL, been through the NEHE tutorials and others and the idea came to me from an app I saw on my phone.

I'm not sure how this would work but my first thought was that its probably needs to be a subclass of JPanel or JFrame for the sake of being able to easily add normal components, but then I'm not sure...

I know I need to become more familiar with JOGL but this is my little Christmas mission but I'd appreciate any suggestions on how i could do this (eventually) or if i should just leave it as an idea and continue to play with the API.

Comment: The only subjectivity I see in the question is asking "can you" vs. "can one". A matter of proper grammar which has been lost in time, really...

Comment: @Ricket thanks for the explanation but then if Can you is not correct, what is? "Could you"?

Comment: "Can one", as in "Can one create a 3D component using JOGL?" since you aren't directly asking *me* if I can create a 3D component using JOGL (the answer would be "not yet", hehe), but you're asking if some*one* can. Or even better, it can be rephrased to "Can a 3D component be created using JOGL?" But yes, @Kos, both are correct, "one" is just more proper and can reduce confusion if you're talking to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of JOGL is that you create a Java component and render GL calls to it. This needs to be an implementer of GLDrawable (typically either GLJPanel if you are working with Swing and GLCanvas if you are not). You can then draw whatever 3D scene you want into it using the JOGL calls, and it behaves like the appropriate kind of Java Component (with a few restrictions).

The other thing you can do is draw your 3D scene offscreen to a GLPbuffer and then draw the resulting bitmap to the screen as part of the component.

Comment: While not strictly how I've done it, your desc. is similar. Migrated to C++ with QT library in the end, got a fairly nice "3D window" done.

Answer (score 1):

Well ., first of all you need to setup Eclipse and create the JOGL library:

- Go to the top menu bar, click Window -> Preferences and click new and type a name for your library, such as jogl-2.0. Leave the System library (added to the boot class path) checkbox unchecked and click ok.
- Back in the user libraries panel, you should see your library appear and click add JARs.. and navigate to the location where you extracted your JOGL library and then open the 'lib' directory, which contains all the various JAR files and native libraries for JOGL. Select the following JARs: gluegen-rt.jar, jogl.all.jar, nativewindow.all.jar, newt.all.jar and click ok to add these four JARs to your user library. You should see them listed under jogl-2.0 now.
- Click native library location and then edit on the right and select External Folder.. and navigate to the same directory all the JAR files for JOGL are in. This should be the 'lib' directory inside the location you extracted the JOGL files, and click ok.

Now you simply have to tell your project to use your JOGL user library, right click the project folder and select Properties, select Java Build Path and click -> Libraries tab at the top -> add library -> select user library and click next, then put a check mark next to JOGL-2.0 and click finish.

I hope that you want to make something created by you and not copied :)

Now ., put the code here to see what you have and if something is wrong.

Comment: You explained how to create a project with JOGL & Eclipse. I thought the question was about how to create component with JOGL that can be used in a way Swing, SWT and AWT components are used. You know, a reusable cylinder component that has properties, i.e. image to put inside a cylinder. Am I wrong? (genuine question, not a rhetorical one)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but unfortunately Rekin is right. I already have JOGL setup in eclipse and netbeans. And yes I'm trying to expermiment and create my own stuff... if i wasn't i wouldn't be learning much at all... Do you have any ideas on how to achieve it? i.e as Rekin aptly described "A re-usable cylinder component that has properties?"